# ‘mach-o, but wrong architecture’ in updated iOS version (>9.3.5)

Tags: ios, xcode8

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/86B94D41-988D-4F2B-8624-588B72CD90B5/BendTheBar.app/BendTheBar
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86B94D41-988D-4F2B-8624-588B72CD90B5/BendTheBar.app/Frameworks/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86B94D41-988D-4F2B-8624-588B72CD90B5/BendTheBar.app/Frameworks/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86B94D41-988D-4F2B-8624-588B72CD90B5/BendTheBar.app/Frameworks/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

For solving ‘mach-o, but wrong architecture’:

1. Go to Target Build Phase.
2. Select ‘Run Script’.
3. Uncheck the ‘Run script only when installing’ option.

   [image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: Didn't work for me. I don't have that check selected but still getting that error